# Validating Uniqueness in Custom Configuration Section

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, app-config

I have the following xsd for a custom configuration section, where `LdapServerSection : ConfigurationSection`, `LdapServerCollection : ConfigurationCollection` and `LdapServerElement : ConfigurationElement` :

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified" 
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               targetNamespace="http://my-namespace.de/LdapServerSection.xsd"
               xmlns:mstns="http://my-namespace.de/LdapServerSection.xsd">
      <xs:element name="ldapServerSection">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ldapServers">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ldapServer">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
(...)
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
              <xs:unique name="UniqueServerName">
                <xs:selector xpath="mstns:ldapServer" />
                <xs:field xpath="@name" />
              </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

If I try to use a duplicate server name, like in this config excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="ldapServerSection" (...) />
  </configSections>
  <ldapServerSection xmlns="http://my-namespace.de/LdapServerSection.xsd">
    <ldapServers>
      <ldapServer name="Development" (...) />
      <ldapServer name="Development" (...) />     
    </ldapServers>
  </ldapServerSection>
```

Intellisense warns me that

> "There is a duplicate key sequence 'Development' for the 'http://my-namespace.de/LdapServerSection.xsd:UniqueServerName' key or unique identity constraint."

While this is expected behaviour, the config is then loaded in spite of the validation error and the second entry overwrites the first one.

So how can I avoid this?